# CloseCommand implementation, multiple views, single model

Tags: wpf

I have a CloseCommand implementation for closing Views from ViewModels (as discussed in several posts/blogs) which is working perfectly, but I am puzzled (unable to understand the logic) with the behavior. (I have removed original lengthy code and replaced it with a simplified version which should be able to convey the question I am trying to ask)

In a model (Model1) I have following parameters and properties

```
private Action _closeAction;
private ICommand _closeCommand;
.....
public Action CloseAction { set { SetProperty(ref _closeAction, value); } }
public ICommand CloseCommand { get { return _closeCommand; } }
```

SetProperty is implemented in base class as following..

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if(Equals(storage, value))
        return false;
    storage = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

In model constructor I have initialized the closecommand as following

```
_closeCommand = new RelayCommand(param=>this._closeAction());
```

I have multiple command implementations in master model (ModelX) which create new views such as following two (in each implementation, same model is passed as command parameter)...

```
private void ShowView1(object param)
{
    Model1 model = param as Model1;
    View1 view = new View1();
    view.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    view.DataContext = model;
    model.CloseViewAction = new Action(view.Close);
    view.Show();
}

private void ShowView2(object param)
{
    Model1 model = param as Model1;
    View2 view = new View2();
    view.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    view.DataContext = model;
    model.CloseViewAction = new Action(view.Close);
    view.Show();
}

and so on for multiple other views...
```

On each view I have a close button which have a binding to CloseCommand

```
Command="{Binding CloseViewCommand}"
```

Now when there are multiple views open using above method, if I click on a close button on a view, that particular view gets closed and no other.

Now my question is, while opening each new view, same single model's CloseAction property is being set with new view's close function. So, shouldn't the close command trigger close the latest view, instead of the correct view.

Please help me understand what is happening behind this.

Thanks & Regards

#### EDIT with master model/view info

In my Master ViewModel I have following commands..

```
private ICommand _showView1Command, _showView3Command, _showView3Command...
```

In constructor

```
_showView1Command = new RelayCommand(param=>this.ShowView1(param));
_showView2Command = new RelayCommand(param=>this.ShowView2(param));
_showView3Command = new RelayCommand(param=>this.ShowView3(param));
...
```

properties

```
public ICommand ShowView1Command { get {return this._showView1Command;} }
public ICommand ShowView2Command { get {return this._showView2Command;} }
public ICommand ShowView3Command { get {return this._showView3Command;} }
...
```

in Master View i have ItemsControl with item datatemplate for Model1 containing following menu entries

```
<MenuItem Header="View1" CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowView1Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
<MenuItem Header="View2" CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowView2Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
<MenuItem Header="View3" CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowView3Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad :(

Thanks a lot Jan Walczak for helping me out. Couldn't have gotten to the root cause unless you hadn't shared your views with me.

Didn't check the code properly first time. Extremely sorry for that. In code there was only one place where the code was exactly like the above one, but at other places views were being created with new viewmodels, which have their own implemented CloseCommands.

At the one place where the same model is being used by multiple views, the CloseAction property of the view gets overwritten and only latest opened view gets closed. But at other places, as the views are opened with new viewmodels (which have their own implementations of CloseCommand), the views get closed properly.

Answer (score 2):

You did create two close actions, each one for certain view. So when calling the close action it has reference to a view it is closing.

```
 model.CloseViewAction = new Action(view.Close);
```

Comment: But wouldn't that be the same object with same property values. As Model is a reference type, so shouldn't model be pointing to the same object as param and hence same object in all views?

Comment: I have updated the post with additional information regarding master model/view

Comment: Could You debug and check if _closeCommand = new RelayCommand(param=>this._closeAction()); is used once or twice?

Comment: Checked, it is called once only in the constructor of Model1.

Comment: And that SetProperty function is called twice? SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
That one.

Comment: I was wrong about model, so i edited my answer. It looks like You create action twice, and the action is for certain view to close.

Comment: I just created a simple test project to test the behavior and it works exactly as I had hoped. Clicking on any view's close button closes newest opened view only. It seems there is some part of code in main project which is causing closecommand action being bind for view in such a way that new changes are not being reflected to newly opened views. Let me check it thoroughly and get back to you.

Comment: But isn't it the fact in my answer? That the close action gets certain view as parameter when u make it ?

Comment: Let me upload the sample code. In the test project I did exactly as I have mentioned above and only the latest view gets closed, not the one on which the click operation was done.

Comment: [Sample code project](http://wikisend.com/download/401052/testCode.7z) This is the sample project which I created to test the behavior.